# How to align these buttons in a row?

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, vertical-alignment

https://jsfiddle.net/2L9mznzu/

There are two empty text button, how to align them into a row?

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
</div>
<div class="button">Button
</div>
<div class="button">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top` property to your `.button`.

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell box.
>   Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

See demo below:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
</div>
<div class="button">Button
</div>
<div class="button">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add vertical-align: middle;

```
.button {
display: inline-block;
width: 80px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
background: gray;
margin: 0 4px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap them inside a container div and use `display:flex;` this way they will always be aligned to the vertical center of the container div.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="button">
</div>
<div class="button">Button
</div>
<div class="button">
</div>
</div>
```