# Why is this not aligned properly with display: inline-block and some text?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know the reason why it aligns differently when there is text or any other element inside the div with display: inline-block? I know vertical-align fixes it, but I am curious to know how the browser determines to display like that.

```css
  div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #dd6b4d;
    display: inline-block;
/*     vertical-align: top; */
  }
  
  .inner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375341

Comment: take the time to read the duplicate question and all the answers and you will understand the magic behind vertical alignment

Answer (score 0):

> The default value of vertical-align (if you declare nothing), is
>   **baseline**

Unless it is overridden, this rule applies. When text is put in the inline-block, that text will create a baseline for the inline-block.

For reference, here is the article on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)

Comment: `When there is no text in the inline-block, then it has no baseline` --> this is false, there is always a baseline, and in the case of an empty inline-block element it's the bottom edge of the element