# Side by side divs behave strange

Tags: html, css

I have this :

```css
.themeMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Preview {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.mag {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: green;
}

.themeTitle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="themeMenu">
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="mag"></div>
  <div class="themeTitle">text here ruin it</div>
</div>
```

Problem : when I don't put text into `themeTitle` its aligned to the right just fine, but if I put one letter inside this div, all of it will go down so `preview/mag` are vertically aligned but `themTitle` goes down.

**EDIT**:

```
`vertical-align:top;`
```

will put the themeTitle in the same height with preview/mag, but the text will be on top, I need all of them to be vertically aligned to center :

( **preview | mag | themeTitle** )

Comment: make a demo in stackblitz.com

Comment: that's the default *baseline alignment* I guess - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375341/

Answer (score 0):

Solve it with :     `vertical-align:top;` , but text is still on top , so added a new h1 inside :

```
  <div class="themeTitle"> <h1 class="fontRoundedText">ff</h1> </div>
```

Then on this h1 ,

```
.themeTitle>h1
{
  vertical-align: center ;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, just insert newline

```
<div class="themeMenu">
  <div class="preview"></div><br>
  <div class="mag"></div><br>
  <div class="themeTitle">text here ruin it</div>
</div>
```